# Error: Invalid AST Node: {"input":"** } on graphql mutation (Amplify client)

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I tried to use example schema on api doc("https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql?sdk=js") like below on Many-To-Many Connections

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  editors: [PostEditor] @connection(keyName: "byPost", fields: ["id"])
}

# Create a join model and disable queries as you don't need them
# and can query through Post.editors and User.posts
type PostEditor
  @model(queries: null)
  @key(name: "byPost", fields: ["postID", "editorID"])
  @key(name: "byEditor", fields: ["editorID", "postID"]) {
  id: ID!
  postID: ID!
  editorID: ID!
  post: Post! @connection(fields: ["postID"])
  editor: User! @connection(fields: ["editorID"])
}

type User @model {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  posts: [PostEditor] @connection(keyName: "byEditor", fields: ["id"])
}
```

I created all items and then I tried to delete them but I failed especially on PostEditor.

There is a mutation to delete PostEditor so I called it like below

API.graphql(graphqlOperation((deletePostEditor, {input: {id},})))

It fails with below error message.

Error: Invalid AST Node: {"input":"b2f7064c-af32-49cd-8c87-*******"}

I think I provided right ID. I checked it on query.

Comment: is it possible to share client side code,`deletePostEditor`

Comment: the code is generated by amplify codegen. the code is like below.

Comment: export const deletePostEditor = `mutation DeletePostEditor(
  $input: DeletePostEditorInput!
  $condition: ModelPostEditorConditionInput
) {
  deletePostEditor(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
    id
    postID
    editorID
    post {
      id
      title
      editors {
        nextToken
      }
      labels {
        nextToken
      }
    }
    editor {
      id
      username
      posts {
        nextToken
      }
    }
  }
}
`;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should pass your parameters as a second parameter of `graphqlOperation`. so , check your parentheses

`API.graphql(graphqlOperation((deletePostEditor, {input: {id},})))`,you have one pair extra parenthesis

below is correct one
`API.graphql(graphqlOperation(deletePostEditor, { input: { id } }))`

- first param=deletePostEditor
- second param={ input: { id } }

tiny mistake, Isn't It?

Comment: I am ashamed of my mistake... I should not turn off eslint or watch the code carefully....

Comment: it happened to all of us don't worry:-)